# catch errors thrown by child directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, try-catch

My app is using some other directives I have no control other and I would like to augment any errors that come from those directives with some information, so that I know which errors are coming from myself and which are not. So I was trying to write my own directive, which compiles any content in a try/catch block so I can catch the errors and handle them appropriately.

I turns out the following code will not catch any errors, presumably because compile is executed asynchronously?

```
// in compile fn:
foreignEl = element.contents().remove();

// in link fn:
element.append(foreignEl);

try{
  $compile(foreignEl)(scope)
} catch(e){
  console.error("NOT MY FAULT: " + e.message);
}
```

I was thinking of using the directive like this:

```
<my-error-catcher>
  <the-foreign-directive>
  </the-foreign-directive>
</my-error-catcher>
```

Should this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your approach of creating a parent directive to catch child directives errors but got nowhere with it, but using [decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator) might be a more proper way of accomplishing your goal of catching errors thrown by directives you have no control of:

```
.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('theForeignDirective', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];
    //copy the directive's original link function
    var directiveLink = directive.link;

    directive.compile = function() {
      try {
        var bindedLink = directiveLink.apply(this, arguments);
        return function() {
          bindedLink.apply(this, arguments);
        };
      } catch(e) {
        console.error("NOT MY FAULT: " + e.message);
      }
    };

    return $delegate;

  });
});
```

Here is a working plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/0Dk3DKhaNrxgSri5G54E